# Android draw line with width

Tags: android, width, line

I know how to draw a line in Android, but how can I set the width of the line?

I tried to draw X lines nearly to have a width of X but I'm sure there is another way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you set your new paint for drawing line on canvas,

just:

```
yourpaint.setStrokeWidth(23);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look in the online reference for android developers.
Link to relevant section with DrawLines() and DrawLines() overloaded version...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html